# how to sniff https packets using scapy in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote this program:

```
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers import http


def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)


def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        url = (packet[http.HTTPRequest].Host + packet[http.HTTPRequest].Path).decode()
        print("=> " + url)


sniff("Wi-Fi")
```

it works on http websites and capture packets without any problem but this program does not work on https websites , I do some research and I found that I should use scapy-ssl_tls module that supports https and I found this code:

```
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers import http, ssl_tls

def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet, filter="tcp port 443")

def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(ssl_tls.TLS):
        if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
            url = (packet[http.HTTPRequest].Host + packet[http.HTTPRequest].Path).decode()
            print("=> " + url)

sniff("Wi-Fi")
```

but I'm unable to install scapy-ssl_tls module because I use python 3.9 on windows 10 and this module not compatible with my stuff and in fact it is very hard for me to install this module on my system, I want someone to help me modify this code to capture https packets like http without using scapy-ssl_tls.